# Span of a set of polynomials and infinite linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, taylor-expansion

[image]

1)Can the set S span the set of all continuous functions?
2)Can it span the set of all functions having Taylor series expansion?
I'm not sure whether second one makes sense.Also in Taylor series we have an infinite series expansion.In span we only consider finite linear combination,am I right?

My doubt is why do we consider finite linear combination even when the set is infinite?Why we haven't defined something called infinite linear combination?

Comment: (1 When talking of linear algebra, yes: only a finite number of the vectors of $\;S\;$ participate in each linear combination. (2) From the above the answer is clear, as not every function is a polynomial. (3) If you "mix" linear algebra and topology and we talk, say, of a topological linear space then linear combinations, Span and etc. change in most cases, when we talk of the closed span of a set of vectors and etc. This though doesn't seem to be what you asked about since there is no appropiate tagging.

Comment: I haven't had any exposure to topology,but why is that we use only finitely many vectors forlinear combination is it because infinite linear combination maybe would be like we have to speak of convergence etc like infinite series?

Comment: Exactly so: only finite linear combinations out of an infinite (or finite) set of vectors.

Comment: Yes,so in linear algebra whenever we say linear combination we actually mean a finite linear combination

Comment: Yes indeed. There are many infinite dimensional spaces which are very important, but within linear algebra every linear combination of any set of vectors must be a finite one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the set of polinomials is insuficient, but the set of power series is a good set for aproximate a continuous functions. The power series is a polinomial of infinity order, for example the taylor series.

Is similar to
[Fourier series for approximate a $2\pi$-periodic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4149218/fourier-series-and-linear-combination/4149225#4149225), if you have questions we can chat about this topic, which departs a bit from linear algebra in finite-dimensional vector spaces.